# Pinch to zoom not working on iPad with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am using the fullPage.js plugin and I can not zoom by pinching on my iPad. I have the following code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff'],
    anchors: ['home', 'concertation', 'essences', 'jeVote', 'lastPage'],
    loopHorizontal: false, menu: '#menu',
    slidesNavigation: true, slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    css3: true,
    keyboardScrolling: false,
    touchSensitivity: 1
})
```

Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please give us an example of your code?

Comment: i just use a plugin fullpage.js

`$('#fullpage').fullpage({
sectionsColor: ['#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff'],
anchors: ['home', 'concertation', 'essences', 'jeVote', 'lastPage'],
loopHorizontal: false,
menu: '#menu',
slidesNavigation: true, 
slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
scrollingSpeed: 700,
css3:true,
keyboardScrolling: false, 
touchSensitivity:1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just implement the pinch to zoom in javascript by putting the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var scale = 0.7; // initial-scale
    var r = 0.10;

    $(document).bind('gesturechange',function(event){

        if(event.originalEvent.scale > 1) scale = scale < 1.2 ?  scale+r : 1.2 ;
        else scale = scale > 0.7 ? scale-r : 0.7 ;

        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, minimum-scale='+ scale.toFixed(2) +', maximum-scale='+ scale.toFixed(2) +', user-scalable=yes'); // 

    });
});
```

and it works perfectly.

Comment: yes, and it worked perfectly on iphone 6, of course, not as the native

Comment: Where did you take the script from ?